# Is there a way to change GPU / CPU on tensorflow during code execution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have 2 tensorflow (1.15.4) models running sequentially. The output from the first model will be fed into the second model.
Is there a way to run the first model using CPU and run the second one using GPU in one python script?

To simplify it, I tried a sample script like below

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())
os.environ.pop("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES")
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())
```

However, both print results are `False` .

Is it possible to switch the device type in the middle of execution of a piece of codes?

Thank you!

---

Update:

According the comments, I tried the tf.device as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device("/CPU:0"):
    code1

with tf.device('GPU:0'):
    code2
```

However, both code1 and code2 are run on CPU. Is there anything I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: you can use "with tf.device" statements for this.

Comment: If you would like a particular operation to run on a device of your choice instead of what's automatically selected for you, you can use with `tf.device` to create a device context, and all the operations within that context will run on the same designated device. You can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#manual_device_placement) for more details. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for both of your ideas. I tried the tf.device, (i added the code in the post), but tensorflow doesn't switch the device type. Do you know is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

GPU cards are not installed properly. That's why you received `False` in both prints. If the GPU card is installed properly, then `tf.test.is_gpu_available` will return `True`.

Since you are using `TF 1.15.4`, please install Tensorflow GPU as shown below

```
!pip install tensorflow_gpu==1.15.4
```

Please refer to the sample working code to use both CPU and GPU as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())


# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  a1 = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
  a2 = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  a3 = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

# Run on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  b = tf.add(a1, a3)

print(c)

# Run on the GPU
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
  c = tf.matmul(a2, a3)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
1.15.4
True
Tensor("Add_1:0", shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
Tensor("MatMul_1:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:0)
```

For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) to install GPU and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) for tested build configurations.